# Temporarily change language for terminal messages/warnings/errors

Tags: command-line, language-support, locale

Messages in my terminal are displayed using Russian language by default, which is my native one.

For just a moment I want them to be in English (eg. to paste in forums), then switch back to the default language.

How can I do the switch and switch back using bash?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are several environment variables available for changing language settings. You can view your current locale settings by executing the `locale` command. To change all locale settings to English, use `LANG=C`. This `C` locale is always available without installing additional language packs. (In order to temporarily change to non-English locales, see [@mklement0](https://askubuntu.com/a/844455/6969)'s post.)

Examples:

Executing a command with the default language settings and print the current locale settings:

```
$ /nonexistent
bash: /nonexistent: Bestand of map bestaat niet
$ locale
LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Temporarily override the language for one program and show that it is really temporary:

```
$ LANG=C ls /nonexistent
ls: cannot access /nonexistent: No such file or directory
$ ls /nonexistent
ls: kan geen toegang krijgen tot /nonexistent: Bestand of map bestaat niet
```

Change the locale for all commands executed in the current shell and include proofs again:

```
$ LANG=C
$ ls /nonexistent
ls: cannot access /nonexistent: No such file or directory
$ locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: For other users having issues getting this to work - setting `LANG` or `LANG_ALL` isn't working for me, yet `LANGUAGE` is. See [Why is overriding the LANG environment variable not changing the language for me?](http://askubuntu.com/q/311767/88802)

Comment: @gertvdijk: Thanks for that; the reason this answer works even without setting `LANGUAGE` is an _exception_: GNU gettext gives precedence to the `LANGUAGE` value _except_ if the (effective) `LC_MESSAGES` value (typically set indirectly via `LANG` or `LC_ALL`) is either `C` or (its synonym) `POSIX`. 
Also note that `LANGUAGE` happens to be unset in this answer, whereas it _is_ set by default, and if it is set, you must override _it_ to switch to a _specific locale's_ language (as opposed to "C" / "POSIX"), which is what you found.

Comment: Your answer works great when switching to the "C" locale (with US English messages, as requsted), but won't work for other locales unless `LANGUAGE` is explicitly unset or overridden. Given the question's generic title, it is likely that people will find this answer looking to switch to a non-English language also, so please consider adding this information to your answer.

Comment: @mklement0 Given the context of the question (posting English error messages), I think that the current post is sufficient. You can add another answer to explain the details around `LANGUAGE` if you want :)

Comment: I've added [my own answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/844455/225111), as you suggested. If you agree with my assessment that future readers may come here looking to switch to _any_ language (as several people have already actively indicated), please add a link to my answer to your question. Aside from that, I suggest changing the value of `LANGUAGE` in your sample output to `nl`, which is the actual default value when your locale is `nl_NL.UTF-8`.

Comment: @mklement0 The output from `locale` on a Kubuntu 16.04 desktop have empty `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL` while the others contain `nl_NL.UTF-8`. I've updated the answer to link to the non-English scenario. (btw, you might want to use less bold-faced text in your post, it is somehow makes it harder to read.)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I appreciate that you've added a link. Good to know that other Ubuntu flavors are configured differently - I've added a note to my answer. As an aside: Arguably, _not_ setting `LANGUAGE` by default makes more sense. Re `LC_ALL`: I don't think any Unix-like OS sets `LC_ALL` by default, as that would _override_ the indiv. `LC_*` variables (rather than set as an _overridable default_, as `LANG` does). Point taken re bolding - I've toned it down.

Answer (score 12):

[Lekensteyn's helpful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142814/225111) works great if you want to switch to *US English* on demand, as the OP requested, but **if you want to switch to a *different* language on demand**, more work is needed.

Before starting, you must install message tables with `sudo apt-get install language-pack-<lang-tag>`, where `<lang-tag>` is a [simple RTF 5646 language subtag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646#appendix-A), such as `es` for Spanish.

### Background info

[GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)-based utilities give precedence to the nonstandard `LANGUAGE` environment variable<sup>[1]</sup>
over POSIX-defined locale environment variables `LC_ALL`, `LC_MESSAGES`, and `LANG` (in that order).

Given that `LANGUAGE` is set by default on Ubuntu systems<sup>[2]</sup>, namely to a *substring* of the `LANG` value that reflects either a simple language tag (e.g., `es` for Spanish) or a language-region tag (e.g., `de_DE` for the Germany variant of German), you must unset or override `LANGUAGE` in order for a different language's messages to take effect.<sup>[3]</sup>

### Option 1: Set `LANGUAGE`

**Example**: Switch to Spanish (`es`) messages ad-hoc:

```
$ LANGUAGE=es ls NoSuchFile
ls: no se puede acceder a NoSuchFile: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

**Note**: A simple language tag such as `es` is sufficient, but you may add a region identifier (e.g., `es_AR` for Argentina), and even a charset suffix (e.g., `es_AR.UTF-8`).
However, localized messages may only exist at the *language* level, and the fallback is to use messages that match the *language* part (`es`, in this case).

### Option 2: Unset `LANGUAGE` and set `LC_ALL`

This alternative solution *undefines* `LANGUAGE` first, and then uses POSIX locale environment variable `LC_ALL` to implicitly set `LC_MESSAGES`<sup>[4]</sup>:

```
$ LANGUAGE= LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8 ls NoSuchFile
ls: no se puede acceder a NoSuchFile: No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

This solution has the advantage of setting *all* localization aspects to the specified locale (such as `LC_TIME` for date/time formats) and by (implicitly) setting `LC_MESSAGES` also informs *non*-GNU programs of the desired language.

Note how `LC_ALL` requires the *exact, full* locale name, including charset suffix, to be effective (`es_ES.UTF-8`) (unlike `LANGUAGE`, for which a simple language tag is sufficient (like `es`)). The same applies to setting `LC_MESSSAGES` and `LANG`. Specifying an invalid / non-installed locale name causes fallback to the POSIX locale and therefore US English.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>[1] The reasons that Lekensteyn's answer works even _without_ unsetting / overriding `LANGUAGE` is an _exception_: if the (effective) `LC_MESSAGES` value (typically set indirectly via `LANG` or `LC_ALL`) is either `C` or (its synonym) `POSIX`, that value is respected, irrespective of the value of `LANGUAGE`, if any. Conversely, if the (effective) `LC_MESSAGES` value is any other, _specific_ locale, `LANGUAGE` takes precedence.</sup>


<sup>[2] This applies to [Ubuntu proper](https://www.ubuntu.com/), but not necessarily to [other flavors](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours); Lekensteyn states that [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) does _not_ set `LANGUAGE`.  
Arguably, `LANGUAGE` should _not_ be set by default, given that in its absence the `LC_MESSAGES` value implied by the `LANG` value (which determines the current locale), is respected.</sup>


<sup>[3] You can also use this approach to switch to [US] English by assigning either `LANGUAGE=C` or `LANGUAGE=POSIX` (as an alternative to, `LANG=C` / `LANG=POSIX`), though I'm unclear whether that is actively recognized or simply a _fallback_ mechanism, given that these values don't start with a _language_ tag; perhaps the better choice would be `en_US`.</sup>


<sup>[4] There's an _edge_ case where this approach doesn't work: Trying to invoke an executable with a _path_ - whether relative or absolute - does NOT switch to the specified language, whereas a _mere filename_ does:  
`LANGUAGE= LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8 /path/to/no_such_utility` does _not_ work (outputs a message in the current locale), whereas  
`LANGUAGE= LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8 no_such_utility` does (outputs a Spanish error message).  
If anyone knows why and whether there's a good reason for this, do let us know.</sup>

Comment: Tip of the hat to @[wjandrea](http://askubuntu.com/users/301745/wjandrea) for his help with structuring this post.