# Software index broken

Tags: installation

When I was installing MTS Mblaz crossplatformui.deb for MTS data connect, its installed partial and shows error, and So I tried to uninstall "crossplatformui" but every time it showed following error.

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 205769 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing crossplatformui ...
ztemtvcdromd: no process found
dpkg: error processing crossplatformui (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossplatformui
Setting up firmware-b43-installer (4.150.10.5-5) ...
--2012-06-01 14:11:21--  http://mirror2.openwrt.org/sources/broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2
Resolving mirror2.openwrt.org... 46.4.11.11
Connecting to mirror2.openwrt.org|46.4.11.11|:80... failed: Connection refused.
dpkg: error processing firmware-b43-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
```

Comment: did you try removal of the package with `apt-get -f remove packagename` option (fixes broken dependencies)?

Comment: yha, I used sudo apt-get -f remove crossplatformui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps carefully.

1. `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatformui.postrm`. This will open that file in gedit text editor with super-user privileges.
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in gedit to search. Write in the search-box `ztemtvcdromd` and comment out those lines which contains the search string by placing `#` at the start of the line(s). 
   If this process seems complicated then simply put `exit 0` after the first line (which should contain `#!/sbin/sh`).
3. save the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatformui.postrm`.
4. then try `dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq  crossplatformui` to uninstall the package.

Comment: And preferably set the locale en_US.UTF-8 which is universally supported instead of Indian English subset :).

Comment: Thanks for reply but when i use that command the following message display       (Reading database ... 205769 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing crossplatformui ...
ztemtvcdromd: no process found
dpkg: error processing crossplatformui (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 crossplatformui

Comment: Please provide the output of the command `locale`.

Comment: Again Thanks for helping me, The output of locele command is as  arvind@arvind-laptop:~$ locale
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Ok, I am editing my answer.

Comment: `en_US.UTF-8` does not have to be universally available. Use the `C` locale, that is always available. Shortcut: `LANG=C locale`. See also http://askubuntu.com/q/142812/6969 on changing locales temporarily.

Comment: @Lekensteyn **true**. But those warnings seem to be harmless, the process tried to fall back to C locale, yet failed. I think the error here is `ztemtvcdromd: no process found`.

Comment: @Samik You're right, using `apt-file search ztemtvcdromd` also makes clear that it isn't a standard application supplied with Ubuntu. As for the locale warnings, it makes the output slightly harder to read.

Comment: @Smik you are right, the problem is occurred when I was installing crossplatformui (which is Not a ubuntu supplied s/w, it is for MTS Internet Data card), that time it failed installation, and then so i was tried to uninstall that, but create this new problem of broken software index. Now nothing is install or uninstall. its through that no such file/directroy **ztemtvcdromd** .

Comment: @SmikLots of Thanks for giving your valuable time to solve my problem,'sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/crossplatformui.postrm.' then 'dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq crossplatformui ' will remove the **crossplatformui** successfully.

Comment: but now i face a new issue **Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]** even my internet connection running properly.

Comment: sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease  
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com nattyInRelease
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg              
Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates InRelease
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com natty Unable to connect toin.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.22 80]
`

Comment: @ArvindGangwar if you are currently in Ubuntu 12.04 or precise then you should remove update channels fro Ubuntu 11.10 or natty from your **software sources** from `synaptic package manager`.

Comment: @Samik Currently I have Ubuntu 11.04 version.

Comment: This seems to be a different issue related with connecting to the software repositories, if the problem is persistent then create a new post(of course search previous similar questions) and make a link to this post as background information.

Comment: @Samik, Thanks for your valuable time to solve this issue, Now I close from my side as my problem is solved, thanks